# Control relative sizes of discrete scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a polar violin plot with `ggplot2`.  I'd like to control the relative size of each category (the width of each category of the factor on the x axis, which then translates to angle once I make the coordinates polar).

Is there any way to do this?

Example code:

```
means <- runif(n = 10, min=0.1, max=0.6)
sds <- runif(n = 10, min=0.2, max=0.4)
frame <- data.frame(
  cat = sample(1:10, size=10000, replace=TRUE), 
  value = rnorm(10000)
) %>%
  mutate(
    mn = means[cat], 
    sd = sds[cat],
    value = (value * sd) + mn,
    cat = factor(cat)
  )
frame %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cat, y = value)) + geom_violin() +
  coord_polar()
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Alternatively (and perhaps better), I'd like to be able to make a polar coordinates chart that isn't centered.  Where the angles are the same for each discrete category, but the points converge, say, 1/3 of the way from the bottom of the circle, rather than in the center of the circle.

Comment: What I'm imagining is like a donut plot, but instead of wedges along the ring, it's violin plots...is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The perhaps better way to do it is by moving the convergence point so its off-center, and then I can just control the order of the categories.

Comment: If you want to add space between the bottom tips and the center of the circle, you can use `ylim` or `scale_y_continuous` to either set limits or expand the scale to go further negative than your data actually is

Comment: I'm not sure how that would address the issue.  Would you mind terribly writing an answer and including a code example and I can try it?  That way if it works, I can accept your answer and you'll get the magic stackoverflow berries for it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, I'm redoing my previous answer. If what you want is a fan/weed leaf shape, you can add dummy data for additional `cat` values. In this example, I just doubled the number of levels in `cat`, but you could change this. Then I set the x breaks to only show the values that actually have data, but let the dummy values take up space to change the shape. Still not sure if this is what you meant but it's interesting to try.

```r
library(tidyverse)

means <- runif(n = 10, min=0.1, max=0.6)
sds <- runif(n = 10, min=0.2, max=0.4)
frame <- data.frame(
    cat = sample(1:10, size=10000, replace=TRUE), 
    value = rnorm(10000)
) %>%
    mutate(
        mn = means[cat], 
        sd = sds[cat],
        value = (value * sd) + mn,
        cat = factor(cat)
    )
frame %>%
    mutate(cat = as.integer(cat)) %>%
    bind_rows(tibble(cat = 11:20, value = NA)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(cat), y = value)) + 
    geom_violin(scale = "area") +
    coord_polar(start = -pi / 2) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:10)
#> Warning: Removed 10 rows containing non-finite values (stat_ydensity).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, Camille.  That actually isn't what I meant.  Imagine taking the center point of the circle, and dragging it down so x is still in the middle of the plot, but y is 1/4 of the way from the bottom to the top.  Sort of like a marijuana leaf.

Comment: So like a fan shape instead of a circle? I'm having a hard time picturing

Comment: Still a circle on the outside.  But instead of all the violins converging in the center of the circle, the violins converge midway to the bottom.

Comment: @Bob see my redo. How's that?

Comment: Closer... now imagine that all of the violins converge not in the center, but on a point somewhere in that middle circle.  I'm thinking I need to change CoordPolar to be hyperbolic.

Comment: So maybe then you could add in the `expand_scale` bit I was trying before to move the minimum y values away from the center...I think you're on to something pretty weird & cool